# Find every word, otherwise a message from grep should appear

Tags: command-line, grep

I have a file with 5 numeric no. Like below

```
Line 1 - 6 rahul
Line 2 - 4 anil 
Line 3 - 8 ravi
Line 4 - 9 sagar
Line 5 - 3 pravin
```

Here if I'm using `grep '8\|9\|2' file >file1.txt`
It will redirect only matching record i.e.

```
Line 4 - 9 sagar
Line 5 - 3 pravin
```

to file1.txt only.
But here I want `2 -- this record is not available from your searching strings` message from grep command.

Comment: Check the `-v` flag. "Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.", from `man grep`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (somewhat inefficiently) using `grep` inside a shell loop. Given

```
$ cat file1.txt
6 rahul
4 anil
8 ravi
9 sagar
3 pravin
```

Then

```
$ for k in 8 9 2; do grep -q "$k" file1.txt || echo "$k not in file"; done
2 not in file
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this using `awk`:

```
$ printf '8\n9\n2\n' | awk '
    NR==FNR{a[$1]++; next} 
    {delete a[$1]} 
    END{for (k in a) print k " not in " FILENAME}
  ' - file1.txt
2 not in file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks bro it's working as per my requirement